# Explaining vector projection in layman terms

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computer-science, programming

I've been working on a project that includes the need to project vectors as outlined here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-drawn-line-follows-a-path.

One of the things that surprised me is that if I'm given something like the below the coverage given is greater than 1. Where we're projecting the squiggly line segment above to the line segment below.

[image]

I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around the math behind it as I'm not from a math background. Would anyone be able to explain what is happening behind the scenes in layman terms that further breaks it down than what's out lined in the above post?

Specifically the sum of all the length of vector projections divided by the length of the line segment you're projecting onto, why is it that this works?

Comment: A projection is the same as a projector in real life, only that we assume all light beams to be parallel, so sunlight is closer to what it is mathematically. This also means that many points (all the points along a light beam) are mapped onto one single point on the screen which is the projection space. Thus the little circle is mapped to a little flat line segment.

Comment: Ohhh, so we're just breaking it down into line segments then I can imagine that the squiggly line broken down after being projected is longer than the projection space hence the > 1? Math is amazing, I'm surprised you break down line segments and then project it to figure what % of some line segment covers another

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by line elements. Imagine the sun far away over your curve, shining on the flat line you drew. So the picture will also be flat, namely a part of the line. You cannot retrieve any information about the curved line from the projection, except for its width.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I think I just need to spend some more time with it and map your explanations, thank you!